# ffmpeg h264_nvenc force level=41

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia

I have some videos at 1080p 60fps.

These videos are with level=50 and my TV plays only videos up to level=41, so I want to convert my videos using ffmpeg and hardware acceleration.

I have a Windows 10 machine with ffmpeg and Geforce 2060, so I try run below command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec h264_nvenc -preset slow -level 4.1 output.mp4
```

but I get this error:

**[h264_nvenc @ 000001dd43cd07c0] InitializeEncoder failed: invalid param (8): Invalid Level.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height**

When I try to run the same command above using "-level 4.2" or above, the encode process works! But it is useless for me, because I really need "-level 4.1".

I noticed that if use libx264 instead of h264_nvenc, the encode process accepts "-level 4.1", but it take too long to complete (I want to enjoy hardware acceleration instead of CPU).

How can I force h264_nvenc to accept "level=4.1" ?

Comment: It looks like the limit of level 4.1 is 30.1fps (when using `h264_nvenc` encoder). It looks like an enforcement of the [following table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels). Try converting to 30fps: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 30 -vcodec h264_nvenc -preset slow -level 4.1 output.mp4`.